# ZIP file replaces .VSIX from Visual Studio Marketplace

Tags: visual-studio-2017, vsix

I'm using Visual Studio 2017. Our organization is blocking Visual Studio Marketplace (403 HostBrowserBlocked). Therefore, the way we normally download and install extensions is failing.

When we find a useful extension on the Visual Studio Marketplace, they want us to download a ZIP file.

What are the instructions for using this ZIP file properly? Apparently this is common knowledge because it isn't clear on the download page.

I have downloaded the ZIP file and looked for the missing VSIX file. I have copied the extracted ZIP file to "Extensions" folder of the Visual Studio installation and still failures.

[image: Gives me ZIP file instead of VSIX.png]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is Internet Explorer renames .vsix to .zip. You can use other web browser to download as .vsix.

Comment: This was very strange but after much research... it is confirmed. Rename file extension from .zip file to .vsix. Thank you Sergey and Grzegorz!

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried to just replace manually the file extension of the downloaded file from `zip` to `vsix`?